# Attribute's ngModel value got undefined when watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a little bit confused about how values are being captured in the directive in AngularJS, I have the following code which works pretty well on testing whether the 2 passwords in the input fields are identical

[html]

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="profileSecret" class="control-label col-sm-4">WPA2 Password:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="password" name="profileSecret" class="form-control" ng-model="profile.secret">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="profileSecret" class="control-label col-sm-4">WPA2 Password (Confirm):</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="password" name="profileSecretRepeat" class="form-control" is-valid-psk="profile.secret" ng-model="profile.secretRepeat">
                </div>
              </div>
```

[Worked js]

```
.directive('isValidPsk',function(){//camel case normalize, remember
        return {
            restrict:'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elt, attr, ctrl){
                scope.$watchGroup([attr.isValidPsk,attr.ngModel],function(newVal, oldVal){
                    validate(newVal[0],newVal[1]);
                });

                var validate = function(value1, value2){
                    if (typeof value1 == 'undefined' || typeof value2 == 'undefined'){
                        ctrl.$setValidity('isEqualPwd',false);
                    }
                    else{
                        var res = value1 != '' && value1 == value2 && (value1.length >= 8 && value1.length <= 64);
                        ctrl.$setValidity('isEqualPwd',res);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    })
```

The above code works perfectly as I expect but I wonder why the below code does not get what I expected, the attr.ngModel just give me "undefined" instead of the actual value of "profile.secretRepeat"?

[js not work]

```
.directive('isValidPsk',function(){//camel case normalize, remember
        return {
            restrict:'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                isValidPsk: '=',
            },
            link: function(scope, elt, attr, ctrl){
                scope.$watchGroup(['isValidPsk',attr.ngModel],function(newVal, oldVal){

                    console.log(newVal[0]);
                    //validate(newVal);
                    console.log(newVal[1]); //>> why this is undefined??
                });
```

Thanks very much for all the help!

Comment: scope.$watchGroup expects a scoped variable that holds some value and can be changed by some external action. You're passing a constant string value, hence the error is thrown.

Comment: @TechMa9iac Thanks for the reply, but I suppose attr.ngModel is not a string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your 1st directive doesn't contain a isolated scope you are getting both updated values inside you `scope.$watchGroup` function.
But in you changed code you us isolated scope inside your directive, which means you current scope doesn't get inherited from child scope. For that you need to explicitly point to the `parent` scope from directive.

**Code**

```
scope.$watchGroup(['isValidPsk','$parent.' + attr.ngModel], function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal[0]);
    //validate(newVal);
    console.log(newVal[1]);
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, if I don't specify the scope, the scope of the directive will share the info of the parent scope, therefore I can watch both of the values, on the other hand, if I put a "scope" in the directive, an isolated scope is created and only the value specified in that scope can be read in directive, therefore for those I haven't specify in the scope object, I cannot get anything.

Comment: @user2499325  yes, if you remove isolated scope, the thing will start working as before..but if you want to stay with isolated scope, then you need to use `$parent.` to point parent variable,,did you tried my above solution?

Comment: Yes I have already tried it, works perfectly, thanks for the correction and clarification!

Comment: Forgot one more question, you said when I do not add scope, then there would be no isolated scope, then in the link function, can I use the provided scope parameter to access other model values (not the one in custom directive)

Comment: Yeah, you could access any scope variable of you controller where element belong